# Subnavbar drop down menu not working

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

My drop down menu was working when I only had one navigation bar, but now that the tutoring pages of my business became sub pages in a website featuring all my businesses, I made the tutoring navigation bar a subnavbar, and at that point, my drop down menus stopped working.  When I hover over "services," "contact me," and "resources," I should see a drop down menu, but I don't, so now there are several pages clients can not access.  I do not get why they stopped working, and I have tried to research this, but I feel like I have done everything right...

CSS CODE

```
    **/* 1st Navigation Bar */**

 #nav {
width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
height: 40px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: rgb(94, 185, 176);
}

.navbar {
height: 40px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
border-right: 1px solid #54879d; 
}

.navbar li  {
height: 50px;
width: 155px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
background-color: rgb(94, 185, 176);
font: normal 200%/110% 'chocolatebox deco regular',sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar a   {                           
    padding: 14px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text        appears centered vertically */
    border-left: 1px solid #74e3d8; /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of blue than the background.   */
    border-right: 1px solid #4d9a92; /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of blue than the background.  */
    text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
    color: black; 
    display: block;
    }

.navbar li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffe643;
    } 

 .navbar li.active {
background-color: #ffe643;
border-bottom: 5px dashed black;
text-decoration: underline;
}

            **/* 2nd Nav bar */**

#subnav {
width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
height: 40px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #ffe643;
 }

.subnavbar  {
height: 40px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; 
border-right: 1px solid #54879d; 
}

 .subnavbar li  {
height: 50px;
width: 155px;
float: right;
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
background-color: #ffe643;
font: normal 200%/110% 'chocolatebox deco regular',sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
}

    .subnavbar a    {                           
    padding: 14px 0;  /* Adds a padding on the top and bottom so the text appears centered vertically */
    border-left: 1px solid #fefefb; /* Creates a border in a slightly lighter shade of yellow than the background.   */
    border-right: 1px solid #fee121; /* Creates a border in a slightly darker shade of yellow than the background.  */
    text-decoration: none;  /* Removes the default hyperlink styling. */
    color: black; 
    display: block;
    }   

.subnavbar li:hover, a:hover {
    background-color: #CFEAE7;
    } 

.subnavbar li.active {
background-color: #CFEAE7;

                    **/* Drop down menu */**      
 .subnavbar li ul   {
    display: none;  /* Hides the drop-down menu */
    z-index: 999; 
    height: 50px;                                   
    margin: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */
    padding: 0; /* Aligns drop-down box underneath the menu item */ 
    background-color: rgb(94, 185, 176); 
    }               

 .subnavbar li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* Displays the drop-down box when the menu item is     hovered over */
     }

.subnavbar li ul li a   {
    border-left: 1px solid #74e3d8; 
    border-right: 1px solid #74e3d8; 
    border-top: 1px solid #4d9a92; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4d9a92; 
    }

.subnavbar li ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #ffe643;
   }
```

HTML CODE (This is the code for both nav bars)

```
    <div id="nav">
    <ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="../Content_Writing.htm">Content Writing</a></li>
<li><a href="../Copy_Editing.htm">Editing</a></li>
<li><a href="../Video_Courses.htm">Video Courses</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="Tutoring/Tutor_Home.htm">Tutoring</a></li>
<li><a href=http://tutorwithkatie.org/Blog/blog-2>Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="../index.htm">Home</a></li>

</ul>
```

```
 <div id="subnav">
     <ul class="subnavbar">
         <li></li>
         <li><a href="#">Resources</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="Resources/English.htm">English Resources</a></li>
               <li><a href="Resources/Math.htm">Math Resources</a></li>
               <li><a href="Resources/Study-Skills-and-Organization.htm">Study skills and organization Resources</a></li>
               <li><a href="Resources/Parent.htm">Parent Resources</a></li>
            </ul>         
         </li>
         <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="Contact/Request-Information.htm">Request Information</a></li>
               <li><a href="Contact/Request-New-Client.htm">Schedule new client appoitnment</a></li>
               <li><a href="Contact/Contact-Details.htm">Contact Details</a></li>
            </ul>         
         </li>

         <li><a href="Policies.htm">Policies</a></li>
         <li><a href="Current-Students.htm">Current Students</a>       
         </li>

         <li><a href="#">Services</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="Services/English-Tutoring.htm">English Tutoring</a></li>
               <li><a href="Services/Homeschool-English.htm">Homeschool English</a></li>
               <li><a href="Services/Algebra-Tutoring.htm">Math Tutoring</a></li>
               <li><a href="Services/Online-Tutoring.htm">Online Tutoring</a></li>
            </ul>         
         </li>

   </ul>
   <div>
```

So I have display: none;   to hide it and then display: block; to show it on hover, but it no longer displays it on hover.  It used to and then the moment I added the first nav bar and called this class .subnavbar, it stopped working....

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because you have a lot of issues:

Extra `*` in your code that are causing CSS issues and are messing up with you CSS. Take all the comment lines out that look like this:

`**/* Drop down menu */**`

and replace them with a valid comment like this:

`/* Drop down menu */`

There also is a missing closing `}` on this CSS rule

`.subnavbar li.active {
background-color: #CFEAE7;`

and also change this line on the `#subnav` from `overflow: hidden;` to `overflow: visible;` to display the SubNav when you hover over it.

`#subnav {
width: 100%; /* Spans the width of the page */
height: 40px; 
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: visible;
background-color: #ffe643;
 }`

Also a missing closing `</div>` tag in the HTML for `<div id="nav">` and also you have a `<div>` instead of a closing `</div>` at the end of the `<div id="subnav">`.

Here is a working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/a1cq345u/2/) for reference where it is working. Hope that clears things up.